# deploy Crystal report on client machine just by copying of rquired DLL?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, winapp

Hello every one
We are using CR 2010 for .net and in client side we need just CR reportviewr 
Are there any walkthroughs that copy crystalreport dll files in Bin directory and copy these file in client machine, run time msi file is huge and we are looking for a way to copy and register just needed dlls (or COM) by hand (programmatically). 
Is it possible?

Any idea is helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible... I'm sure. In reality, though, no. It's like asking what's needed in a .Net install. Sure you could pick and choose, but why bother? SAP has made it very easy to install Crystal now with their MSI installs. I've worked with Crystal for over 15 years, and it's NEVER been this easy and consistent.

Comment: Thank you Jeff
yes it is easy but it is a big file about 60 MB.
we want to make a smaller package that could be downloaded by slow internet connection.

Comment: I respectfully say you're wasting your time, and you're going to be spending A LOT more time debugging problems after they download a subset of the Crystal DLLs than if you would just have them download all of it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, we give up this and try to use other report tools